# Evaluate the following infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to evaluate the following infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{a^{2^n}+1}$, where $a$ is a real number?

It seems as if Vn method may help but how do I use it? {Vn method is expressing nth term as a difference of two consecutive terms.}

Comment: what is vn method. what have you tried?

Comment: can you define a ?

Comment: The body of the Question should be as self-contained as possible, and should not rely entirely on the title for its meaning.  Please elaborate the wording of your Question and supply more context, e.g. what was the "Vn" method and how did you try to apply it?

Comment: V(n) method is mere telescoping only..To cancel out the middle terms leaving us with the first and last only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: you can prove easily that :
$$\frac{2^n}{a^{2^n}-1}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{a^{2^{n+1}}-1}=\frac{2^n}{a^{2^n}+1} $$